# Microsoft hosted agent is unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-hosted-agent

I am unable to see microsoft hosted agent in azure devops for private project.
I sent an email to azpipelines-freetier@microsoft.com to grant free tier 4 days ago, and still no response from them.
Could you please advise how can request microsoft hosted agent for free tier.

Also, I requested for the region change for my project 4 days ago, however the request yet not completed.
Can anyone suggest on it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To request the free tier, include the following information in your email:

- Your name
- Name of the Azure DevOps organization
- possibly a brief description of your intent

> Please note that it takes us **2-3 business** days to review and
> respond to your request. If everything is in order, we enable the free
> tier directly. If not, we may contact you for additional information.
> If you do not have the free tier in your organization **a week** after
> your request and if you did not hear from us in that timeframe, please
> follow up with us.

This is stated in this official [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/change-in-azure-pipelines-grant-for-private-projects/comment-page-2/).

From the actual case, it may take 4 to 5 working days to complete the application:

[image]

Comment: Agent is available now